# How to create a new datetime from parts of dates and string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date

How would I take the month, append `"/01/"` to it, then append the year to it, and finally append `"00:01 AM"` to it. I would like it end up looking like this:

```
2018/01/01 00:01 AM
```

I managed to do it in `ACCESS` but cannot accomplish this in SQL Server. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start over. What exactly is your starting point? Is it a string? If so, what does it contain (and what pattern do you expect)? If not, is it a date or datetime or int or what?

Comment: I have a datetime field with '2018-01-02 13:45:30.000' as the value. More or less, how can I change the day in that date to 01 and the time to 00:01 AM. I need to do it for the whole column, and the days and time vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Concat`,`Cast`,`Year`,`Month` and `right`

replace `getdate()` with your variable/field

```
select cast(concat(year(getdate()),right(concat('0',month(getdate())),2),'01',' 00:01 AM') as datetime)
```

or

```
select convert(varchar(22),cast(concat(year(getdate()),right(concat('0',month(getdate())),2),'01',' 00:01 AM') as datetime),100)
```

Comment: Thank you. The first one worked perfectly! Getdate() worked better because I am pulling previous month data. I just wonder how I'm gonna contend with the year once January rolls back around and I want to pull December data. I'm trying to get this all automated as a monthly task.

Comment: then use `dateadd(month,-1,getdate())` ... if today is january

Comment: Would that roll back the year as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result with this script:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME;
SET @Date = '2018-01-02 13:45:30.000';
SELECT CAST(YEAR(@Date) AS CHAR(4)) + '/' + CASE WHEN MONTH(@Date) >= 10 THEN '' ELSE '0' END + CAST(MONTH(@Date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01 00:01 AM';
```

#### Edit:

You can also create a function and make it reusable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.InitializeDate(@Date DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(19)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(YEAR(@Date) AS CHAR(4)) + '/' + CASE WHEN MONTH(@Date) > 10 THEN '' ELSE '0' END + CAST(MONTH(@Date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01 00:01 AM';
END
GO

-- Usage example:
SELECT dbo.InitializeDate('2018-01-02 13:45:30.000') AS MyDate;
GO

-- Output:
2018/01/01 00:01 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways obviously - and always mention the version you are using since that affects the functionality that is available. I will say that it is **highly** unusual to require a time portion as you describe. I fear you have made an assumption and chosen a path that may turn into a problem. I suggest you read [Tibor's](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes) discussion of the datetime datatype (and everything else as well). One possible way - which is really to demonstrate the functionality available in steps to get you thinking - is:

```
set nocount on;
declare @x datetime = '20180102 13:45:30.000';
with cte as (select cast('20180102 13:45:30.000' as datetime) as d1 union all
    select '20180101 13:45:01:997' union all
    select '20180228 00:00:05.003' union all
    select '20120229 12:11:30.007') 
select d1, 
datefromparts(year(d1), month(d1), 1),
dateadd(second, 1, cast(datefromparts(year(d1), month(d1), 1) as datetime)) 
from cte;
```